# CollectionViewSource Filter a Collection view with a list of items

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, collectionviewsource

i will try to explain my problem best i can,
i have my collection view:

```
 CollectionViewSource ArticoliProduzioneViewSource;
```

that need to be filtered by 3 list of items

```
 public ObservableCollection<BLL.Models.Serie> ListaSerie { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<BLL.Models.Serie>();  

 public ObservableCollection<BLL.Models.Prodotto> ListaProdotti { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<BLL.Models.Prodotto>();

 public ObservableCollection<BLL.Models.Colore> ListaColori { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<BLL.Models.Colore>();
```

[image]

this is the screen of what i need to do, only to let you understand, i need to filter the items inside the first datagrid(the collectionviewsource) with the items in the 3 smaller datagrids (the 3 observablecollections that i have figured before)

```
    private void CollectionViewSource_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Accepted = 
        (ListaSerie.Count != 0 ? ((BLL.Models.ArticoloProduzione)e.Item).ArticoloSerieProdotto.Serie.Id == Serie.Id : true)
        &
        (ListaProdotti.Count != 0 ? ((BLL.Models.ArticoloProduzione)e.Item).ArticoloSerieProdotto.Prodotto.Id == Prodotto.Id : true)
        &
        (ListaColori.Count != 0 ? ((BLL.Models.ArticoloProduzione)e.Item).Colore.Id == Colore.Id : true)
        ;

    }
```

this is what i tried, it works, but it filters the main collectionview only with the last
item that i have inserted in one of the 3 filter list.

what i need to do here is just to filter the main CollectionView with all the items that
are included in the 3 observable collections that i use as filters.
hope you understand, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Found The Solution to my question, this is it! hope it helps someone!

```
 public bool ControlloSuSerie(int idarticolo)
        {
            bool risultato = false;
               for (int i = 0; i <= ListaSerie.Count - 1; i++)
              {
                if (ListaSerie[i].Id == idarticolo)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    risultato =  false;
                }
            }
            return risultato;
        }
        public bool ControlloSuProdotto(int idarticolo)
        {
            bool risultato = false;
            for (int i = 0; i <= ListaProdotti.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (ListaProdotti[i].Id == idarticolo)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    risultato = false;
                }
            }
            return risultato;
        }

        public bool ControlloSuColore(int idarticolo)
        {
            bool risultato = false;
            for (int i = 0; i <= ListaColori.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (ListaColori[i].Id == idarticolo)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    risultato = false;
                }
            }
            return risultato;
        }

        private void CollectionViewSource_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Accepted = (CodiceArticolo != null && CodiceArticolo != "" ? ((BLL.Models.ArticoloProduzione)e.Item).Codice == CodiceArticolo : true) &
                 (ListaSerie.Count != 0 ? (ControlloSuSerie(((BLL.Models.ArticoloProduzione)e.Item).ArticoloSerieProdotto.Serie.Id)) : true)&
                 (ListaProdotti.Count != 0 ? (ControlloSuProdotto(((BLL.Models.ArticoloProduzione)e.Item).ArticoloSerieProdotto.Prodotto.Id)) : true)&
                 (ListaColori.Count != 0 ? (ControlloSuColore(((BLL.Models.ArticoloProduzione)e.Item).Colore.Id )) : true);
        }
```